# How to wire up AutoFac to Common.Logging?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dependency-injection, mocking, autofac

I have a class like so:

```
public class LoggedFoo
{
    private readonly ILog _logger;

    public LoggedFoo(ILog logger)
    {
        this._logger = logger;
    }

    public DoStuff()
    {
        this._logger.Info(i => i("Doing stuff..."));
    }
}
```

One of the business requirements is that logs are being generated for certain functions, so naturally I want to mock out the `ILog` to verify.

However, Common.Logging library supports type-based loggers, along the lines of:

```
var logger = LogManager.GetLogger<LoggedFoo>();
```

...or:

```
var logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(LoggedFoo));
```

The problem is, we are using AutoFac for dependency injection, and I cannot figure out how to instantiate an `ILog` based upon the class that is being instantiated for injection.

How do I write this?  I am using the latest Nuget version of AutoFac.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can think on 2 ways to achieve it:(well sorry the hour is 1:50 am in my country...)

1. Change your `ILog` to `ILog<T>` and then register it as an [Open Generic](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/register/registration.html#open-generic-components).
2. Use [Dynamic-Providers](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/register/registration.html#dynamically-provided-registrations) which allows you to resolve with a context.

`Autofac`'s website has an [example](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/examples/log4net.html) which seems to be the exact thing you were looking for.

Resolve the dependency with a context:

```
private static void OnComponentPreparing(object sender, PreparingEventArgs e)
{
    var t = e.Component.Target.Activator.LimitType;
    e.Parameters = e.Parameters.Union(
    new[]
    {
      new ResolvedParameter((p, i) => p.ParameterType == typeof(ILog), 
                            (p, i) => LogManager.GetLogger(t)),
    });
}
```

Attach to:

```
protected override void AttachToComponentRegistration(IComponentRegistry componentRegistry, IComponentRegistration registration)
{
    // Handle constructor parameters.
    registration.Preparing += OnComponentPreparing;

    // Handle properties.
    registration.Activated += (sender, e) => InjectLoggerProperties(e.Instance);
}
```

Comment: Where do these methods go?

Answer (score 2):

So recently I decided the best way to do this was not to inject the `ILog` interface, but rather the `ILogManager` interface, like so:

```
public class Foo
{
    private readonly ILog _logger;
    public Foo(ILogManager logManager)
    {
        _logger = logManager.GetLogger<Foo>();
    }
}
```

By doing this, I cut out a lot of the headscratching necessary to figure out which logger needed to be referenced.  I defined my `ILogManager` class once with an `SingleInstance` lifetime and never looked back.

Comment: How did you get an instance of ILogManager?

Comment: in my IoC wireup, I just do something like: `builder.RegisterType<LogManager>().SingleInstance().As<ILogManager>();`

Comment: Ah, TIL about RegisterType. Thanks!