# ASP.NET Core Dependency injection for Common.Logging

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc, common.logging

I want to be able to configure ASP.NET's dependency injection framework to be able to resolve me an instance of [Common.Logging's ILog](https://github.com/net-commons/common-logging/blob/master/src/Common.Logging.Core/Logging/ILog.cs) interface. Creating an instance of ILog is done via the [Common.Logging's static LogManager](https://github.com/net-commons/common-logging/blob/master/src/Common.Logging.Portable/Logging/LogManager.cs).GetLogger methods which require a type as a parameter.

This means that when resolving an instance of ILog I need to know the target type that the DI engine is trying to inject into. In the past I've used autofac modules to solve this problem which [other have asked about here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31974924/how-to-wire-up-autofac-to-common-logging), but it would nice to be able to do this purely with [ASP.NET's built in Ioc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection).

I can see that there is the ability to resolve an instance by creating a method that takes an IServiceProvider, but there is no context of the type being injected into that I can see.

Does anyone know how a service can be resolved at runtime with knowledge of the type its being injected into?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted the [same question in the ASPNET dependencyinjection repo](https://github.com/aspnet/DependencyInjection/issues/543) issue register and apparently its not possible.